# error 1004 when trying to set cell value to value of string

Tags: vba, excel

I've seen this question a few times but haven't found a solution that is applicable to my situation, so here it goes:

I have a fairly complicated formula that I want to insert into a cell (complicated as in it's a pain in the butt to follow).  I have the components set up in variables, and running the sub give me the correct final variable name in the locals window, however when I try to set the cell to the formula I get a '1004: application-defined or object defined error'.  the output should look like this:

Cell A1:    =BDS("0","pg_segment","dir = h", "number_of_periods = -3")

However it returns nothing.

I have tried the following:  setting the final variable (cmdstr0) to an integer-- this works.  As a string ("asdf") also works.  Altering the value directly (.value = "string") works.  The only thing that doesn't work is when VBA builds the formula itself to insert into the string.  Here's the code, and thank you:

```
sub populate_revenues()

'field = bloomberg field to look up
'direction = output direction (horizontal/vertical)
'geoverride = override to display only geo or product segments
'periods = numbe of periods to display
'cmdstr = the string to be output that will download the data


Dim field As String
Dim direction As String
Dim geoverride As String
Dim periods As String
Dim cmdstr3 As String
Dim cmdstr2 As String
Dim cmdstr1 As String
Dim cmdstr0 As Variant

Let cmdstr2 = 0

Let field = Worksheets("output").Cells(1, 3).Value
Let direction = "Dir = " & Worksheets("output").Cells(1, 5).Value
Let geoverride = " product_geo_override = " & Worksheets("output").Cells(1, 7).Value
Let periods = " number_of_periods = " & Worksheets("output").Cells(2, 3).Value
Let cmdstr1 = "=BDS(" & Chr(34)
Let cmdstr3 = Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & field & ", " & Chr(34) _
& direction & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & geoverride & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & periods &     Chr(34) & ")"


Let cmdstr0 = cmdstr1 & cmdstr2 & cmdstr3
'Let cmdstr0 = 1

Let Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(10, 1).Value = cmdstr0

End Sub
```

Also, can anyone please tell me if there's a faster way to format as code than hitting space-bar four times every line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know, you must double-up on the double quotes.  So if you want:

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A10,"apples")
```

you must use:

```
Sub demo()
    Range("B9").Formula = "=COUNTIF(A1:A10,""apples"")"
End Sub
```

I, personally, have a lot of trouble with this.  What I do to debug is to place an apostrophe at the start of the formula:

```
Sub demo()
    Range("B9").Formula = "'=COUNTIF(A1:A10,""apples"")"
End Sub
```

This allows me to "see" the text of the formula and fix problems.

**B.T.W**

To create a code block, hi-light the code and use the paired braces {}

Comment: Thank you!  I had totally forgotten the double-quote thing.  One more question:  why doesn't Chr(34) (") work?

Comment: I wish I could give you a good answer.  I find the whole business of embedded double-quotes very frustrating.

Comment: @smpat04 probably syntax error on your end. I have not tested your code but I note that something simple like this will work using Chr(34): `ActiveCell.Value "=" & Chr(34) & "hello" & Chr(34)`